Fuzzy search in Oracle REST SODA
I am trying to do a fuzzy search using rest from a c# script and have tested a few different ways without success.
This payload works:
string payload = "{ \"name\" : \"Peter\"}";

...which is a normal search after the name "Peter".
However, when trying to do a fuzzy search using the following payloads:
string payload = "{ \"q\": { \"name\": { \"$regex\": \".*Peter.*\" } } }";

Response:
Success response from DB: {"items":[],"hasMore":false,"count":0}

Next:
string payload = @"
        {
            ""q"": {
                ""name"": { ""$like"": ""%Peter%"" }
            }
        }";

Result:
Success response from DB: {"items":[],"hasMore":false,"count":0}

Next:
string payload = @"
        {
            ""q"": {
                ""$textContains"": {
                    ""name"": ""Peter""
                }
            }
        }";

Result:
DB Error: BadRequest
Response: {"type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1","status":400,"title":"The field name $textContains is not a recognized operator.","o:errorCode":"SODA-02002"}

Any help is highly appreciated.

I did solve this by deploying the following code doing a hard coded search for "Pet":
async Task<string> FuzzyReadDb(string _accessToken, string _playerName)
{
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); // Clear headers to ensure no old or unwanted headers are included
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Use the $like operator to search for the specific name
        string payload = "{ \"name\" : { \"$like\" : \"%Pet%\" }}";

        Debug.Log($"Sending payload: {payload}");

        var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://{url}/ords/xxxxxxx/soda/latest/NameTest?action=query", content);
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Success response from DB: {responseBody}");

            // Deserialize the JSON response into a C# object
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseResult>(responseBody);

            // Process the data to extract and display all names
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            if (result != null && result.items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in result.items)
                {
                    // Display each name found in the response
                    output.AppendLine($"{{\"name\":\"{item.value.name}\"}}");
                }

                // Update UI with all names
                txt_Msg.text += output.ToString();
                return output.ToString(); // Return all names as output
            }

            return "No matching items found.";
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"DB Error: {response.StatusCode}\nResponse: {responseBody}");
            return $"DB Error: {response.StatusCode}\n{responseBody}";
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Request Error: {e.Message}");
        return $"Request Error: {e.Message}";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Unexpected Error: {e.Message}");
        return $"Unexpected Error: {e.Message}";
    }
}

Response was:
{"name":"Peter"}
{"name":"Petter"}
{"name":"Petra"}
{"name":"Peter2"}

